# Error message appears after a long period in real device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic. I have a REST API, I get JSON by "http.get" fucntion. My code is following

```
$timeout(function () {
  //$ionicLoading.show();
  $scope.results = "";
  $http.get("http://192.168.10.221:8080/api/public/offers/")
    .success(function(data) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $scope.serverError=false;
      $scope.results = data;
      $scope.offerId=$stateParams.offerId;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $scope.errorOnGet = 'Server Error';
      console.log('data error');
      $scope.serverError=true;

    })
    .then(function(results){
      things = results.data;
    })
}, 2000);
```

but when my server is down, I need to show an error message. For that I tried to implement error function and in my front end I have implemented like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Offers">
<ion-content>
<span ng-show="serverError" class="animate-if">
<ion-label fixed>Server error encountered. Please try again later.</ion-  
label>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It is working fine in browser, error message appears instantly in browser. But in real device the error message appears after a long period. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: `192.168.10.221:8080` - is this the ip of your local or server ?

Comment: Yes, it is IP of my local server